# How to eliminate duplicate rows while read multiple sheets in one excel file in python?

Tags: python

Results will be duplicate while reading more than one sheet from Excel File.

I am able to read multiple sheets but it is giving duplicated results.

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("D:\Personel\Collection.xlsx")
max_nb_row = 0
for sheet in book.sheets():
  max_nb_row = max(max_nb_row, sheet.nrows)
  print("No.of sheets in the File",max_nb_row)
  print("No.of rows in sheet",sheet.nrows)
  for row in range(max_nb_row) :
      print("Rows:",row)
      for sheet in book.sheets() :
          x = sheet.row(row)
          print(x)
```

Code printing rows from both sheets two times. In First Iteration total rows from both sheets same in the second Iteration.
But expected is First Iteration total rows from the first sheet and second Iteration total rows from sheet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("D:\Personel\Collection.xlsx")

sheets = book.sheets()
print("No.of sheets in the File:", len(sheets))
for sheet in sheets:
    rows = sheet.nrows
    print("No.of rows in sheet:", rows)
    for row in range(rows) :
        x = sheet.row(row)
        print(x)
```